# How to put number inside a circle in pure html?

Tags: html

I am a graphic designer and new to coding.

Can someone let me know **how do I put a number inside a circle** in pure HTML? I am putting it inside a table.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: `&#9312;` - leads to ①

Comment: @ceejayoz damn, that's clever. Codegolf winner here

Answer (score 0):

First, create your Circle in CSS..

```
#circle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(38, 165, 166) 0%, rgb(124, 26, 94) 100%);
      border-radius: 50%
    }
```

This will be shown in a HTML container with id `circle` ..

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Inside this DIV you can put whatever number you like..

```
<div id="circle">69</div>
```

It might not align properly, so you cann modify the CSS to play.

```
text-align: center;
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cts5u1y6/)

Good luck with your learning, but you should show some effort when asking a question too.

EDIT//

For your pure HTML version.. You can just add the CSS to inline..

```html
<div style="width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(38, 165, 166) 0%, rgb(124, 26, 94) 100%);
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;"><h1>
69
</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Is it possible to do this with just pure HTML without CSS? Can you let me know what do you mean "show some effort when asking question"? So next time I'll know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: hmm not really.. Maybe an SVG element in html could be drawn.. but why torture yourself ?

Comment: @foreverlearner4 I updated with a html only..

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS `background-radius` property set to `50%`.

An example:

```css
.encircled {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="encircled">42</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HTML` with `CSS`.

Below is the CSS Code:

```
 .circle{
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: relative;
    }
```

HTML code should be:

```
<div class="circle">

    <p>1</p>

 </div>
```

```css
.circle{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

<p>1</p>

</div>
```

Comment: What extra info does this offer the answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Table in HTML can be inflexible so there many ways you can write your code to suit your needs, but this is an idea behind it.
HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><span>1</span>First Element</li>
    <li><span>2</span>Second Element</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li>span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;  /* black border */
  border-radius: 50%;   /* for round enclosing border */
}
```

This should work and editable. Comment for further notice.